# Matlab error : ??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals

Tags: matlab, function

I've a problem with a function that I've written by myself. I've not found in any question how to solve it by myself so I post it here hoping that someone's going to see what I didn't see... (It's my first question and I don't know how to format it in Matlab code, I'm sorry about it)

Here is my function, which calculates the incident angle of a ray (given by the segment CD) on a 'wall' (given by AB). AB (the wall) is supposed to be horizontal or vertical and segment CD and wall AB are supposed to have an intersection :

```
function angle = incidentAngle(AB,CD)

%AB and CD are two vectors of size 1x4
%AB = [a1 a2 b1 b2] et CD = [c1 c2 d1 d2]
%AB is a segment from the point (a1,b1) to the point (a2,b2)


    if(AB(1)==AB(3)) % The wall is vertical
        if(CD(1)==CD(3)) % The "ray" is vertical too, the angle is 90° or pi/2
            angle = pi/2;
        else
            angle = abs(atan((CD(2)-CD(4))/(CD(1)-CD(3))));
        end
    else
        if(AB(2)==AB(4))% The wall is horizontal
            if(CD(2)==CD(4)) % The "ray" is horizontal too, the angle is 90° or pi/2
                angle = pi/2;
            else
                angle = abs(atan((CD(1)-CD(3))/(CD(2)-CD(4))));
            end
        end
    end

end
```

The problem (for example) is that :

when I define AB and CD as

```
AB = [0 1 0 5];
CD = [-1 2 3 4];
```

and that I do

```
angle = incidentAngle(AB,CD)
```

in the command window, I get the message error :

```
??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

And I don't understand why...

If now I just copy the function in the command window, like this :

```
AB = [0 1 0 5];
CD = [-1 2 3 4];

angle = 0;

if(AB(1)==AB(3)) % The wall is vertical
    if(CD(1)==CD(3)) % The "ray" is vertical too, the angle is 90° or pi/2
        angle = pi/2;
    else
        angle = abs(atan((CD(2)-CD(4))/(CD(1)-CD(3))));
    end
else
    if(AB(2)==AB(4))% The wall is horizontal
        if(CD(2)==CD(4)) % The "ray" is horizontal too, the angle is 90° or pi/2
            angle = pi/2;
        else
            angle = abs(atan((CD(1)-CD(3))/(CD(2)-CD(4))));
        end
    end
end

angle
```

I get the right answer,

```
angle =

0.4636
```

Comment: I made a new function in my workspace and tried to re-create your error using your inputs and it worked fine for me. Not quite sure what the issue is. I'm using R2012b btw

Comment: What I do not understand is why it works fine but not when I call the function... The function is (I think) well written and the function is saved in the right folder and though it just don't run...

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054047/subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logicals-generic-sol) for [the generic solution to this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054048/983722).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a built in Matlab function called `angle`, overwriting it with your variable name is inviting  trouble.  Try to change that variable name, say with the name `angl` instead. This should solve your problem.

Comment: @mwoua did you change the name of your function as well?

Comment: it worked for me when I used `function angl = incidentAngle(AB,CD)` and change all `angle` variable occurrences to `angl`

Comment: When I changed all my "angle" to "angl", it didn't worked... But when I changed the function name to "incidentAngl", it worked.

Thanks !

Comment: Just a last thing, how do you highlight (is it a correct word? I'm Belgian and do not know the right word... Anyway) a word like "function angl = incidentAngle(AB,CD)" in your comment ?

Comment: use the ` sign before and after the word you want to highlight.

Comment: @natan the problem is there... Again. Don't you have another idea to fix this ?

Comment: yesterday you said it worked. what happened? I copied your code, change all the `angle` variable to a different name, and it worked for me. (as I also wrote already).

Comment: @natan The problem is... I didn't change anything !
It sometimes says `"??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions."` which is impossible since I verified that all my arguments are 1x4 (and they are) and sometimes `"??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals."`

The fact that it's sometimes one and sometimes the other is really bizarre.

Comment: The problem seem now to be only `??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.`. Although, in my code, I do this : 
<br/>
`firstSegment
size(firstSegment)
wall = mur(n,:)
size(mur(n,:))
incidentTransmissionAngl2 = incidentAngl(wall,firstSegment);`
And my command window returns me 
>>
`firstSegment = 0    4.8889    2.5000    3.5000
ans = 1     4
wall = 5    10     5     6
ans = 1     4

??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.`

Comment: It now works... I really don't understand what is happening. Anyway. It works. Praise the lord